# Shortcut to select current path in Finder in Mac OS

Tags: macos

Is there a shorter way to select and copy to clipboard a path of a current directory in Finder than using `right-click->Get Info->select the path`? Is there a way to show the current path that is **selectable** in the Finder window? This is one functionality that I really miss from Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in solution to your problem, besides ditching Finder and getting comfortable with the terminal.

Otherwise, there is an applescript solution that can be [found here](https://superuser.com/questions/371513/how-to-tell-full-path-of-file-on-mac), that you can turn into a service. By doing so you give yourself the ability to use a custom keyboard shortcut, e.g. Command+control+c, which would indeed be the fastest way in finder to get the current path into the clipboard.